# How to encode this URL properly in java?

Tags: java

I have a String that needs to be encoded and will eventually be appended to a URL. For example,

I need to append the following String

```
String str  ="/content/documents/arg/Periódico Mural 26 01 2015 (01).pdf";
```

Will be dynamically appended to:

http://www.example.com

How do I encode String str so that forward slash is not encoded?

I tried

```
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(str , "UTF-8");
```

But it encodes the slashes as well. I get following:

```
encodedUrl = %2Fcontent%2Fdocuments%2Farg%2FPeri%C3%B3dico+Mural+26+01+2015+%2801%29.pdf
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Note: I have no knowledge of host part and can't use that to form a java.net.URI object. I saw some suggestions on that. I just need to be able to encode String str correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not encode the file name separately.

```
String str = "Periódico Mural 26 01 2015 (01).pdf";
String encodedUrl = "/content/documents/arg/" + URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Well, that's the thing. The string can consist of any characters, so I will need to encode whatever comes through and append to URL. I was just using the one in my post as an example. I was hoping to avoid string tokenizing - there must be a better way to do this!

Comment: Other that `URI`, I don't know if there is a way to do what you want unless you split the string on `/` or replace `%2F` with `/` after encoding. I'll remove my answer someone has a better one.